# Blazor Accordion fails to open in Blazor Foreach

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have an accordion on my page that is created dynamically from the database - The accordion works with static data, opens and closes as expected but as soon as i add a foreach loop and my dynamic data - The data is loaded but the javascript doesn't seem to fire to open the accordion.. Anybody have any idea?

JS -

```
function AccordionStart() {
    const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click",
            function() {
                const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                    panel.classList.remove("open");
                    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false")
                } else {
                    let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion.active");
                    for (let j = 0; j < active.length; j++) {
                        active[j].classList.remove("active");
                        active[j].setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false")
                        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
                        active[j].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("open");
                    }
                    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                    panel.classList.add("open");
                    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', "true")
                }
                this.classList.toggle("active");

            });
    }
}
```

Static Data Accordion (working)

```
<!--Accordion-->
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="faq">
                        <button class="accordion" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span id="tab-title-dimensions_tab">What is Admiral Ackbar's favorite type of music?</span>
                            <div class="circle-animation closed">
                                <div class="horizontal"></div>
                                <div class="vertical"></div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                        <div class="panel" style="">

                            <p>Trap.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="separator120"></div>
                    <div class="separator20"></div>
                </div>
```

Now i add my foreach loop and call to the database, which doesn't work (baring in mind, this MoveStageModel is populated with a click of a button..) -

```
<div class="container">
                    
                @if (ProcessSteps != null)
                {

                    @foreach (var steps in ProcessSteps)
                    {


                        <div class="faq">
                            <button class="accordion" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span id="tab-title-dimensions_tab">@steps.ProcessName</span>
                                <div class="circle-animation closed">
                                    <div class="horizontal"></div>
                                    <div class="vertical"></div>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                            <div class="panel" style="">

                                <p>Trap.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="separator120"></div>
                        <div class="separator20"></div>
                                                  
                    }
                }
            </div>
```

I have tried to place my null check and foreach after the button class accordion and it works, although obviously my data is being outputted horribly. It's as if the javascript cant change the class when it is in a foreach loop.. not sure why.

Now if i place the foreach loop and the null check after the accordion class, the accordion opens, obviously not the way i want it too.. But it seems like the foreach loop is blocking the javascript somehow..

[image]

```
 <!--Accordion-->
                <div class="container">
                   


                            <div class="faq">
                                <button class="accordion" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                @if (ProcessSteps != null)
                                {

                                    @foreach (var steps in ProcessSteps)
                                    {
                                        <span id="tab-title-dimensions_tab">@steps.ProcessName</span>
                                        <div class="circle-animation closed">
                                            <div class="horizontal"></div>
                                            <div class="vertical"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                                    
                                    </button>
                                <div class="panel" style="">

                                    <p>Trap.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="separator120"></div>
                            <div class="separator20"></div>
                                                   
                    
                </div>
```

**Ok i found a fix - So the issue was with my Javascript, when the page loaded the loop was showing 0 items when rendering the page, i put an alert to check this - Not sure if this is the correct thing to do, but i called the onAfterRenderAsync after the items have been populated as below**

```
<div class="container">
                    
                    @if (ProcessSteps != null)
                    {

                        @foreach (var steps in ProcessSteps)
                        {


                            <div class="faq">
                                <button class="accordion" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span id="tab-title-dimensions_tab">@steps.ProcessName</span>
                                    <div class="circle-animation closed">
                                        <div class="horizontal"></div>
                                        <div class="vertical"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                                <div class="panel" style="">

                                    <p>Trap.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="separator120"></div>
                            <div class="separator20"></div>
                                                   
                        }
                         OnAfterRenderAsync(true);
                    }
                </div>
```

Comment: Blazor keeps its own copy of the DOM, you can't in general mix JS and C# changes to the same element(s).

Comment: Blazor is all about rendering and rerendering, I don't know when you are executing your JS function `AccordionStart` but I would guess that the event handlers that you tried to set are either never set (because the JS function would be executed before the elements are rendered) or canceled (because the elements have been rerendered).

Comment: @HenkHolterman my data is outputted but when i click the row, the row does not expand.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine if i place both my dynamic and static version on the same page, the static accordion still opens, where as the dynamic won't open.. when looking at the developer console, i can see the javascript changing the class on the static versions, but doesn't change the classes on the dynamic version.

Comment: I found a fix, in the main post - seems like i needed to call my JS again, onAfterRender to force my javascript to reload.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in a tangle of JS and Blazor component code.  See Henk's comment for the pitfalls.  You can write the whole thing much more cleanly in C# code.  I've copied and pasted your code but I can't get it to work to see exactly what's going on, so I've resisted from posting a generic this is how to do in Blazor answer.

Comment: This is something you should do entirely within Blazor. There is not need to use JS. Use JS only for the things which are not supported by Blazor - like viewport sizes and text events such as selection/copy-paste.